# PyMySQL and Socket Start together

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, pymysql

I start a Socket:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 50011))
sock.listen(1)
sock.setblocking(1)
c, a = sock.accept()
```

If Client connect,
Then:

```
connection = pymysql.connect...
```

Then Crash.

Can not both modules work together?
I need Socket and pymysql.
I also tried to let the two modules work separately on a thread. Unfortunately this did not work. I still get the same error.

Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\AT Programmierung\Python\Kommunikation Server-Client\pymysql\connections.py", line 916, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\AT Programmierung\Python\Kommunikation Server-Client\ServerThread.py", line 23, in mysql
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
  File "C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\AT Programmierung\Python\Kommunikation Server-Client\pymysql\__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\AT Programmierung\Python\Kommunikation Server-Client\pymysql\connections.py", line 706, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\AT Programmierung\Python\Kommunikation Server-Client\pymysql\connections.py", line 963, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dj-eki.de:3306' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was originally trying to connect using:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='dj-eki.de:3306',
```

However, that was wrong and wasn't working.

Instead, I needed to separate the port from the host, like so:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='dj-eki.de',
                             port=3306,
```